# Undefined filed exception when searching with facet in solr

Tags: java, solr, cassandra, datastax

I am using a facet field in my solr query. The query has fired almost 100000 times in the last 3 days. Out of all these times it has intermittently failed 4 times with the below exception:

```
undefined field: "facetfieldname"
```

Not sure what the issue is. Below is my decoded query:

```
q=tenantid:"value"+AND+appinstid:"value"+AND+status:"Open"&shard.shuffling.strategy=SEED&shard.shuffling.seed=value&terms=true&rows=0&start=0&facet.field=facetfield&facet=true&facet.limit=-1&facet.mincount=0&facet.offset=0
```

Below is the full stack trace:

```
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
 at com.xxxx.scheduler.impl.SchedulerTaskManager$TaskWrapper.call(SchedulerTaskManager.java:621) [scheduler-18.2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
 at com.xxxx.scheduler.impl.NonAnalyticsTask$SchedulerTaskCallable.call(NonAnalyticsTask.java:145) [scheduler-18.2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
 at com.xxxx.scheduler.impl.NonAnalyticsTask$SchedulerTaskCallable.call(NonAnalyticsTask.java:212) [scheduler-18.2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
 at com.xxxx.scheduler.util.UpdatePolicyCountUtil.updatePolicyCount(UpdatePolicyCountUtil.java:82) ~[scheduler-18.2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
 at com.xxxx.services.eventmgt.impl.AlertEventManagerImpl.searchPolicyEventCountUsingSolr(AlertEventManagerImpl.java:602) ~[event-management-service-18.2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
 at com.xxxx.common.dao.impl.search.SolrClient.executeQuery(SolrClient.java:403) ~[data-access-service-18.2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
 at com.xxxx.common.dao.impl.search.SolrClient.runQuery(SolrClient.java:588) ~[data-access-service-18.2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.0.jar:4.8.0 1589874 - thetaphi - 2014-04-24 20:55:02]
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:91) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.0.jar:4.8.0 1589874 - thetaphi - 2014-04-24 20:55:02]
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.0.jar:4.8.0 1589874 - thetaphi - 2014-04-24 20:55:02]
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.0.jar:4.8.0 1589874 - thetaphi - 2014-04-24 20:55:02]
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:554) ~[solr-solrj-4.8.0.jar:4.8.0 1589874 - thetaphi - 2014-04-24 20:55:02]
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: undefined field: "facetfieldname"
```

My solr mapping xml contains the below:

```
<field name="facetfieldname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Adding version details:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.15.1403 | DSE 4.8.9 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]
```

Can someone please help out.

Comment: What version of DSE are you using?

Comment: DSE 4.8.9
show version;
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.15.1403 | DSE 4.8.9 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]

Comment: @AlexOtt: Any idea as to why this may happen?

Comment: You need to check logs on all machines to see, if this errors is thrown by single server, or on all. I suspect that one of the machines may have not fully working index, but that's strange - then it should be visible all the time.

Comment: I would also recommend to upgrade to at least 4.8.16 (latest in 4.8), and start upgrade to the 5.0-5.1, as support for 4.8 will be stopped in ~4-5 months

Comment: I have been checking logs from all machines, this happens once out of no where across servers so dont think indexing is an issue. Thanks for the help.